# Video Settings AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, video-encoding

I have a live stream published as below:

```
var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings;
h264Settings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3_2);
h264Settings.setQuality(0, AppSettings.CAMERA_QUALITY);
h264Settings.setMode(userCamera.cameraWidth, userCamera.cameraHeight, userCamera.cameraFps);

streamPublisher = new NetStream(fc.nc);         
streamPublisher.attachCamera(userCamera.getStream());
```

The video information looks like this:

```
Video
  Format : AVC
  Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
  Format profile : Baseline@L3.2
  Format settings, CABAC : No
  Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frames 
  Format settings, GOP : M=1, N=30
  Frame Rate Mode : constant
...
```

Is there a way for me to adjust "Reframes", "GOP" and "Frame Rate Mode" from within my code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the "Frame Rate Mode" and "Reframes", but at least according to [this repo I found](https://github.com/kaltura/krecord/blob/master/KalturaRecord/src/com/kaltura/recording/controller/KRecordControl.as#L348-L367), you should be able to control GOP by using the [setKeyFrameInterval](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setKeyFrameInterval()).

It is possible that the different levels of the H264 settings might give you different number of Reframes.